# ControlsFX TextField validation

Tags: javafx, java-8, controlsfx

How can I validate the text field to be contained only float values using ControlsFX validator?

```
TextField price = new TextField();
ValidationSupport validationSupport = new ValidationSupport();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, read [this documentation](https://javadoc.io/static/org.controlsfx/controlsfx/8.40.16/org/controlsfx/validation/Validator.html)

All you need to do is this type of code where you bind validator with TextField:

```
ValidationSupport validationSupport = new ValidationSupport();
validationSupport.registerValidator(textField, Validator.createEmptyValidator("Text is required"));
```

Instead of `Validator.createEmptyValidator` you have to create validator using Regex expresion / Pattern like this: `^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$`

Then you can validate your text.

Comment: Dead link. BTW the ControlsFX documentation varies between non-existent and shithouse.